# ForeFront TMG server is removing bits of URL

Tags: microsoft-forefront

My ForeFront TMG server is removing window.location.hash from url provided before redirecting user to the default page.

so I have a url like,

```
www.example.com/sites/default.aspx#id=2342|someTable
```

Now ForeFront server is trimming the last bit and i get this after logon

```
www.example.com/sites/default.aspx
```

Any idea what could it be ?

Comment: Is TMG doing forward or reverse proxying? What kind of Logon?

Comment: @ChrisS Logon is for SharePoint, and not sure about proxying, I will have a look and let you know as I am new to TMG